# How to detect if it's running on iPhone or iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, device

I have an app that runs on iPhone, however when I submit to Apple for review, they are testing it on iPad. How do I detect if it's running on iPad for an iPhone app? I tried using `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` but apparently it works only for universal app but not iPhone app.

Comment: First when u start the app u have to select only for iPhone not Universal

Comment: Yes i select iPhone but how to know if it's running on iPhone or iPad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this `UIDevice` Class Method

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]              // like "S R Nayak's iPhone"
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]             // like @"iPhone", @"iPod Touch"
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel]    // localized version of model
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName]        // like @"iPhone OS"
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]     // like @"4.0"
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]  // UDID, a unique string to identify the device
```

Otherwise you can check:

```
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone &&
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] hasPrefix:@"iPad"]) {
// This app is an iPhone app but running on an iPad
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a step back and ask what you need that information for.

Every iPhone app can be run on an iPad or an iPod Touch. If you make the assumption that your app can make phone calls, then this assumption will obviously be wrong. The processor might be unexpectedly fast. But in principle, your app should just run unchanged, and the fact that Apple runs it on an iPad shouldn't make any difference to you. There are hundred thousands of iPhone apps that all run without any problem on an iPad, and without any developer work.

Your app will obviously not be told that the user interface is UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad because you have an iPhone app, and it is supposed to show the iPhone UI even on an iPad.

Comment: I'll tell you why. The reason is because an iPhone banner ad and an iPad banner ad has different size and location. If Apple test an iPhone app on an iPad, the banner ad will be in the middle of the screen, obstructing the user from using the app, thus making the app being rejected. That's why the app needs to know whether it is running on iPhone or iPad.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information from

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]
```

[UIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/model)